# Pointer Not Aligned to Address

Tags: xcode, firebase

Few weeks ago it has been informed that Firebase framework is generating a warnings like "Pointer Not Aligned to Address" on Xcode 8.3..
I was having 32 and now 67. Google dev. was working on it, does it clear to anybody when the update will be pushed ?

Comment: You can track this page for updates https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/271

Comment: Anyone still having this issue - update your Firebase SDK to 3.16.0 and it'll be gone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same worked for me. Follow the lines in your project directory commandline:

`pod repo update`

and then after the first line is finished:

`pod update`

Hint: I've got an error when I was trying to do the second line, but the solution was simple.If you got that error go ahead and include this line to your Podfile:

`project 'path/to/project/projectname.xcworkspace'`

or the `.xcodeproj` file.

hope your project works fine, as mine did.

Answer (score 4):

This issue seems to be fixed in Firebase 3.16.0. This helped me:

```
pod repo update
```

Then:

```
pod update
```